# Nginx - src/core/ngx_sha1.h:19:17: no such file or directory

Tags: nginx, compilation, compiler-errors, makefile

I try to install nginx with nginx-push-stream-module

```
./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx --add-module=../nginx-push-stream-module
make
make install
```

After I run 'make', I got this message:

```
In file included from src/core/ngx_crypt.c:12:0:
src/core/ngx_sha1.h:19:17: fatal error: sha.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sha.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: First of all, you must check the (full) path.  
Did you download the [module (Push Stream)](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpPushStreamModule) and extract it ? Where is the module ?  
Did you get any trouble with the download or the archive ? Did you check the integrity (md5 etc) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue on Ubuntu by installing openssl libs:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl openssl-dev
```

Then did a make clean and:

```
./configure --add-module=../nginx-push-stream-module
```

and run make again.